# Having issues targetting my classes with SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

In my project there's a section where a CSS grid is supposed to display items similar to this:

[The grid with the grid items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WCpt.png)

I did my markup as such:

```
<section class="section-b py-2">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="section-heading">
      <span class="section-heading-line"></span>What can we do for you<span class="section-heading-line"></span>
    </h2>
    <div class="section-b-grid">
      <div class="section-b-grid-item-1">
        <h3 class="grid-item-number">01</h3>
        <strong class="grid-item-title">Complex Detailing</strong>
        <p class="grid-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, impedit.</p>
      </div>
```

And this is my SCSS code:

```
    .section {
  &-heading {
    color: $primary-color;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    position: relative;
    &-line {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50%;
      background: rgba($color: #ccc, $alpha: 0.6);
      height: 1px;
      width: 390px;

      &:nth-child(odd) {
        left: 0;
      }
      &:nth-child(even) {
        right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  // SECTION A:  LANDING
  &-a {
    #landing-image {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    #landing-content {
      margin-top: 5rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: right;
      h1 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: right;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        font-weight: lighter;
        letter-spacing: 7px;
        position: relative;
      }
      p {
        position: absolute;
        left: 12rem;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        color: $primary-color;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        img {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0.75rem;
          left: -0.5rem;
          height: 60px;
          width: 10px;
          transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // SECTION B:  WHAT CAN WE DO FOR YOU
  &-b {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    background: $secondary-color;
    &-grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 1rem;
      grid-template-areas: '
      item-1 item-1 item-4
      item-2 item-3 item-4
      item-2 item-3 item-5
      ';
      &-item {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that there's multiple .section-b-item classes and I want them all to share some common styles before I go in and edit them individually (.section-b-item-1 would nested within &-item as &-1, for example).

I ensured multiple times that I nested everything properly (&-b is .section-b).  My SASS compiler is functioning properly as well.  I threw a display: none in my &-item selector to test if I was targetting them properly but it didn't work.  I've tried to target my grid item classes directly in the global scope as well but to no avail.

I don't understand why this is happening since the markup I've entered seems to correspond with the SCSS.

Comment: Is that SASS code meant to be nested in other code you aren't showing? You shouldn't have a `&` selector at the root level.

Comment: @Sean Yes, I have a .section-a and .section-b class that are nested respectively (&-a and &-b are both within .section).

Comment: Please update the code in your question to reflect that.

Comment: @Sean Okay done.

Comment: If I copy/paste your code into https://www.sassmeister.com/ , it reports a syntax error on line 74.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `&[class*="heading"]` rather than `&-heading`?

Answer (score 1):

You use `section-b-grid-item-1` class in markup while your SASS generates the "display: none" rule for `.section-b-grid-item`. Correct your class in the markup for proper targeting.